# <nav> vs <article> for SEO

Tags: html, seo

In term of SEO, if I want to group relevant page content together to maximize search engine readability, should I use the tag `<nav>` or `<article>`?

Comment: SEO is out of the question.

Comment: You should use what's appropriate. Put navigation elements in `nav` and content in `article`, and don't try to game the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It's not there yet.

2) If it was, and you were wrapping menus as `article`, or wrapping affiliate link-farms as `article`, Google would slap you (keep that in mind in three or four years).

3) If you have lots of legitimate content, and each piece of content is self-contained (ie: suitable for `article`), then not only should you wrap it in an `article` tag, but you should also learn how to use Google's "Rich Snippet Tool", which was recently renamed "Structured Data Tool".

If you learn how to mark things up, both in an html5-friendly way, and in a Google-friendly microformat, then GoogleBot will grab all of the content it knows how, and it will be displayed in search results and elsewhere, when relevant.

Like I said...  ...that's if you've got content which is worthy of doing this, because otherwise, Google will slap you, eventually, if you try to use it for evil.

Answer (score 0):

**article tag**:-
                  The  tag allows to mark separate entries in an online publication, such as a blog or a magazine. It is expected that when articles are marked with the  tag, this will make the HTML code cleaner because it will reduce the need to use  tags. Also, probably search engines will put more weight on the text inside the  tag as compared to the contents on the other parts of the page.

**nav tag**:-Navigation is one of the important factors for SEO and everything that eases navigation is welcome. The new  tag can be used to identify a collection of links to other pages.

so both tag have their own functionality which can be implemented according to need.